# nbconvert not adding custom.js

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I converted a .ipynb file to html using the command:

```
ipython nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to html
```

It contains the **custom.css** link

```
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but no **custom.js**.

My custom.js and custom.css are located at:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/
```

How can i include the custom

```
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```

while using nbconvert.